# Get USB Storage Drive Letter VBSCript

Tags: vbscript, usb-drive

Here is a which shows list of connected USB storage devices.

```
On Error Resume Next
    strComputer = "."
    Dim oFSO, oDrive
    Set oFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = 'USB'")
    For Each objItem in colItems
      Wscript.Echo objItem.Caption
    Next
```

I need to get the drive letter, but it is impossible with the code above. There is no property about Drive Letter for colItems. I can use another script which supports Drive Letter, here it is:

```
Dim oFSO, oDrive
Const USBDRIVE=1
Set oFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives
If oDrive.DriveType = USBDRIVE And oDrive.DriveLetter <> "A" Then
WScript.Echo oDrive.DriveLetter
End If
Next
```

But in this script I can not use Caption Property because it is not supported :( I need to combine these two scripts to get every USB Storage Caption and Letter. How Can I do that? Possible?

Comment: Have you determined what should the code do if the USB drive is mounted in a folder without a drive letter?

Comment: I need Also NTFS or FAT format of usb drive which is not possible with first script. Both scrips have some features which I need to combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This code :

```
'Show drive letters associated with each
ComputerName = "."
Set wmiServices  = GetObject ( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" _
    & ComputerName)
' Get physical disk drive
Set wmiDiskDrives =  wmiServices.ExecQuery ( "SELECT Caption, DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = 'USB'")

For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
   ' x = wmiDiskDrive.Caption & Vbtab & " " & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID 
    'Use the disk drive device id to
    ' find associated partition
    query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"    
    Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery(query)

    For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
        'Use partition device id to find logical disk
        Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" _
             & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition") 
x = ""
        For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
            x = x & wmiDiskDrive.Caption & " " & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & " = " & wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID
Wscript.echo x

        Next      
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Is there any way to skip External Hard Drives?

Answer (score 1):

Derive your desired output from next script (commented as necessary and with self-explanatory output). Written to launch with either `wscript` or `cscript` host)

```
' VB Script Document 28556806.vbs
option explicit
On Error Goto 0

Dim ComputerName, strRslt, strQuery
Dim wmiServices _
  , wmiDiskDrives, wmiDiskDrive _
  , wmiDiskPartitions, wmiDiskPartition _
  , wmiLogicalDisks, wmiLogicalDisk

strRslt = Wscript.ScriptName _
    & vbTab & "Drive letters associated with disk drives" _ 

ComputerName = "."

Set wmiServices  = GetObject ( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" _
    & ComputerName)
' Get physical disk drive
Set wmiDiskDrives =  wmiServices.ExecQuery ( _
    "SELECT Caption, DeviceID, InterfaceType FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
    strRslt = strRslt & vbNewLine
    strRslt = strRslt & vbNewLine _
      & "DiskDrive.Caption = " & wmiDiskDrive.Caption _ 
      & vbNewLine & "DiskDrive.InterfaceType = " _
          & wmiDiskDrive.InterfaceType

    'Use the disk drive device id to find associated partition
    strQuery = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" _
        & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID _
        & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"    
    Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery(strQuery)

    For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
        'Use partition device id to find logical disk
        Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
            ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" _
             & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID _
             & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition") 

        For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
            strRslt = strRslt _
              & vbNewLine & "DiskDrive.Caption = " _
                  & wmiDiskDrive.Caption _
              & vbNewLine & "DiskDrive.DeviceID = " _
                  & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID _
              & vbNewLine & "DiskPartition.Partition = " _
                  & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID _
              & vbNewLine & "LogicalDisk.DeviceID = " _
                  & wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID 
        Next      
    Next
Next

WScript.Echo strRslt
```

I have conceived my answer in a wider approach to make easier deciding among more USB drives attached; appropriate properties could be found at  [Computer System Hardware Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx)